# Strange deprecation in ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember-simple-auth

I am using `ember-simple-auth`,
and recently I have started receiving this deprecation `[deprecation id: ember-simple-auth.configuration.routes]` in my tests

I have such options in config

```
'ember-simple-auth': {
        authenticationRoute: 'login',
        routeAfterAuthentication: '/',
        routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: '/',
},
```

To fix this deprecation do I need to specify this fields for all routes which are use 
corresponding mixins? As for me its too many duplications or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

According to `ember-simple-auth` author

You really should specify route fields for each route with ESA mixin

[details](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/1337)